# How to Change the title of SQL query according to parameter passed on stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which accepts value @OrderType and if Ordertype is Production i want heading as ProductionDate and if it is TakeDown I want heading as TakedownDate.

```
DECLARE  @OrderType nvarchar(50);
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FromDate, 101) AS [PostingDate]
FROM    table
```

//if ordertype is posting then output is

```
PostingDate
1/1/2018
```

//if ordertype is TakeDown then output is

```
TakedownDate
1/1/2018
```

Comment: please give some sample data.....

Comment: Aliases are identifiers, and you can't paramaterize identifiers in SQL.  
Your only option is to use dynamic sql. Beware - if you have parameters for the query itself do not use `exec (@sql)` but build a proper parameterized query and use `exec sp_executeSql` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work for you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure
    @OrderType nvarchar(50)
AS

IF @OrderType = 'Production'

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FromDate, 101) AS [ProductionDate]
    FROM table

ELSE IF @OrderType = 'TakeDown'

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FromDate, 101) AS [TakedownDate]
    FROM table

ELSE

    -- Perhaps some exception handling or a default value here...

;
```